# How to search files with A and without B in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: regex, boost, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Using the Sublime Text 3 file search feature is it possible to search for files within a directory (and all its subdirectories) to see if they contain string `A_STR` (or RegExp `/A_STR/`) but do not contain `B_STR` (or RegExp `/B_STR/`)?

Comment: This turned out to be surprisingly tricky. I've added `regex` and `boost` tags to your question to get the question more focused attention. Note that Sublime Text uses the [Perl Regular Expression Syntax via Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
\A(?:(?!B_STR)[\s\S])*A_STR(?:(?!B_STR)[\s\S])*\z
```

**Explanation:**

```
\A                          # beginning of file
  (?:(?!B_STR)[\s\S])*      # Not B_STR, you may use use \bB_STR\b
  A_STR                     # A_STR, you may use use \bA_STR\b
  (?:(?!B_STR)[\s\S])*      # Not B_STR, you may use use \bB_STR\b
\z                          # end of file
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Just adding that `\b` matches a word boundary.